# DRF: Adding 'url' field to Serializer results in 'could not resolve URL' error when browsing API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django REST Framework and have been frustrated for a while by something that seems very simple. I have a Serializer that I'm trying to switch to a HyperLinkedModelSerializer. I went through the DRF quickstart guide, and I think my Serializer and Viewset are very similar to the examples in there:

```
class PickViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

  queryset = Pick.objects.all()
  serializer_class = PickSerializer

class PickSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  sheet = SheetSerializer()
  game = GameSerializer()
  class Meta:
    model = Pick
    fields = ('url', 'sheet', 'amount', 'spread', 'pick_type', 'pick_team', 'game')
```

With the router addition:

```
router.register(r'pick', PickViewset, base_name='picks')
```

When the `url` field is left out, the pick endpoint shows up on the browseable API and I can view the objects. However, as soon as I add `url`, I get this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /api/pick/
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "pick-detail". 
You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

My understanding was that using a ViewSet would deal with the detail view automatically, and I think the model is included properly. That leaves the lookup_field, but I'm not sure what's wrong here. I'd expect issues retrieving any results.

I tried adding `lookupfield = 'id'` to PickViewset, but that didn't help. I also tried doing the same thing with the GameSerializer- creating a Viewset and adding to the router, but I'm hitting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew this had to be simple, and that turned out to be true. I was using a base_name for PickViewSet, which was unnecessary. I'm still not sure why that didn't work (I tried changing the base_name to 'pick' to match the model name, but that didn't work either), but I'm going to keep reading on how the ViewSets autogenerate the detail views.

Simply removing the base_name was enough for it to start working.